# Multiple Persistent Volumes with the same mount path Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I have created 3 CronJobs in Kubernetes. The format is exactly the same for every one of them except the names. These are the following specs:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: test-job-1 # for others it's test-job-2 and test-job-3
  namespace: cron-test
spec:
  schedule: "* * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
          containers:
          - name: test-job-1 # for others it's test-job-2 and test-job-3
            image: busybox
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            command:
            - "/bin/sh"
            - "-c"
            args:
            - cd database-backup && touch $(date +%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M).test-job-1 && ls -la # for others the filename includes test-job-2 and test-job-3 respectively
            volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: "/database-backup"
              name: test-job-1-pv # for others it's test-job-2-pv and test-job-3-pv
          volumes:
          - name: test-job-1-pv # for others it's test-job-2-pv and test-job-3-pv
            persistentVolumeClaim:
              claimName: test-job-1-pvc # for others it's test-job-2-pvc and test-job-3-pvc
```

And also the following Persistent Volume Claims and Persistent Volume:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: test-job-1-pvc # for others it's test-job-2-pvc or test-job-3-pvc
  namespace: cron-test
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Delete
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
  volumeName: test-job-1-pv # depending on the name it's test-job-2-pv or test-job-3-pv
  storageClassName: manual
  volumeMode: Filesystem
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: test-job-1-pv # for others it's test-job-2-pv and test-job-3-pv
  namespace: cron-test
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/database-backup"
```

So all in all there are 3 CronJobs, 3 PersistentVolumes and 3 PersistentVolumeClaims. I can see that the PersistentVolumeClaims and PersistentVolumes are bound correctly to each other. So `test-job-1-pvc` <--> `test-job-1-pv`, `test-job-2-pvc` <--> `test-job-2-pv` and so on. Also the pods associated with each PVC are are the corresponding pods created by each CronJob. For example `test-job-1-1609066800-95d4m` <--> `test-job-1-pvc` and so on. After letting the cron jobs run for a bit I create another pod with the following specs to inspect `test-job-1-pvc`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: data-access
  namespace: cron-test
spec:
  containers:
    - name: data-access
      image: busybox
      command: ["sleep", "infinity"]
      volumeMounts:
        - name: data-access-volume
          mountPath: /database-backup
  volumes:
    - name: data-access-volume
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: test-job-1-pvc
```

Just a simple pod that keeps running all the time. When I get inside that pod with `exec` and see inside the `/database-backup` directory I see all the files created from all the pods created by the 3 CronJobs.

**What I exepected to see?**

I expected to see only the files created by `test-job-1`.

Is this something expected to happen? And if so how can you separate the PersistentVolumes to avoid something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this is caused by the PersistentVolume definition: if you really only changed the name, all volumes are mapped to the same folder on the host.

```
 hostPath:
    path: "/database-backup"
```

Try giving each volume a unique folder, e.g.

```
 hostPath:
    path: "/database-backup/volume1"
```

Comment: I marked it as the accepted answer because it seems to solve the problem of mount paths. However I am now noticing that when I inspect each `pvc` there are some files missing and not being created every minute like the schedule says so. I can see that each job pod is created and executed without any errors however files are missing. What could that be?

Comment: I'm hardly an expert on the matter, but I noticed the filename of the file you're generating contains the minute as the smallest unit. Perhaps you're sometimes overwriting older files when the time between jobs isn't exactly one minute but slightly less. You could try adding seconds to the filename and see what happens.